Bootstrap Capacitor in Half-Bridge
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887a/slua887a.pdf
In the above app note:

Can someone explain what the IHB_fsw term repersents?
How is I_HB different to I_HBS?

I_HB is HP pin quiescent current, and I_HBS is leaking current. And I_HB/Fsw is a charge in coulombs.
